# How to extract a number marked with specific word from text string in Google Data Studio

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

I have a text string that contains several instances of numbers, example of the data is below.

I am trying to extract the number of keys (the number that is followed by the text -keys). I tried several  `REGEXP_EXTRACT` patterns without luck.

> {38-keys,fit-out,closed,eddy-tamy,datechange-feb2025,staff-onboard,sandy-brighton,open-dec2020}
>
> {same-year,budgeted,signature-done,mark-picard,hotel,5-keys}
>
> {active,building,itsa-signed,2322-keys,pending-signature,next-year-(construction),opening-feb2024}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 0) Summary

- Use #1 **OR** #2 **OR** #3 below (added two additional suggestions as the author received an error with #1 and then #2 in regards to the [`CAST`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7280720) function which may be a result of spacing, Data Source (PostgreSQL) specific or another issue).

### 1) With [`CAST`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7280720)

It can be achieved by using the [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) below (where `Field` represents the respective field name) which extracts all digits immediately preceding `-keys`; the [`CAST`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7280720) function was added to ensure that the field **Type** is **Number** (the default field **Type** of [`REGEXP_EXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7050487) values are **Text**); also, for future reference, the [Raw Input Literal](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/10495775) `R` was used so that `\d` represents the sequence for a digit vs the default (without `R`) in Google Data Studio, which requires two back slashes (`\\d`):

```
CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(Field, R"(\d+)-keys") AS NUMBER )
```

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/ab8fd97b-70b2-4557-849d-38cbed223b37) (Embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ySaNEWCFAsfCJFf642URY-a0wL5bDY_WkHsN9FB8bhs/edit?usp=sharing) Data Source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]

### 2) Without [`CAST`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7280720)

Create the [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) field below at the Data Source and change the field **Type** from **Text** to **Number**; in regards to the difference between the [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) below and and the one above, the one below removes the [`CAST`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7280720) function:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Field, R"(\d+)-keys")
```

[Added a New Page](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/ab8fd97b-70b2-4557-849d-38cbed223b37/page/tJlAC) to the Editable Google Data Studio Report (Embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ySaNEWCFAsfCJFf642URY-a0wL5bDY_WkHsN9FB8bhs/edit?usp=sharing) Data Source) and a GIF to demonstrate:

[image]

### 3) Two [Calculated Fields](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685)

First create the the `RegEx_Field` (3.1 - Support Field) and then the `CAST_Field` (3.2 - Primary Field, where `RegEx_Field` represents the name of the respective field created in 3.1):

**3.1) `RegEx_Field`** (Support field, thus hide field at the Data Source if required)

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Field, R"(\d+)-keys")
```

**3.2) `CAST_Field`** (The field that will be used in the Report)

```
CAST(RegEx_Field as NUMBER)
```

[Added another Page](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/ab8fd97b-70b2-4557-849d-38cbed223b37/page/qUmAC) to the Editable Google Data Studio Report (Embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ySaNEWCFAsfCJFf642URY-a0wL5bDY_WkHsN9FB8bhs/edit?usp=sharing) Data Source) and a GIF to visualise the process:

[image]